# Div centered in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, center

I'm creating gym manager and I would like to have divs to be centered in mobile devices. I have div centered in laptops webbrowsers but there is a problem in mobile browser. In mobile devices my popup div is aligned right
Here is my CSS.

```
.white_content_exDescription {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left:24%;
width: 50%;
margin-top:-70px;
min-height: 335px;
height:auto;
max-height: 500px;
padding: 16px;
border: 16px solid orange;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Here is my webpage www.egymmanager.pl please click on "Opis zajęć" buutton.

Do You have any idea how to centered div in mobile devices? Any javascript or jquery?

Comment: A couple questions/comments.  First, why is display set to none?  Second, if you want to center it, you shouldn't have absolution positioning with left at 24%.  Have you tried left/right margins set to auto?

Answer (score 0):

try this CSS

```
.white_content_exDescription {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left:-25%;
top:50%:
width: 50%;
margin-top:-160px;
min-height: 335px;
height:auto;
max-height: 500px;
padding: 16px;
border: 16px solid orange;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```